# Error with apt-get update: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file

Tags: apt, software-sources

I am getting an error in `sudo apt-get update`. Can anyone please help me fix it? Ubuntu 16.04

```
W: Invalid 'Date' entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/
  developer.download.nvidia.com_compute_cuda_repos_ubuntu1604_x86%5f64_Release
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the software source list file mentioned in your error messages got corrupted somehow.

Delete the invalid list file and then let `apt` fetch it again from the repository server:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/developer.download.nvidia.com_compute_cuda_repos_ubuntu1604_x86%5f64_Release
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Again it's the same error after executing above lines.

Comment: Can you show me the corresponding sources.list entry? You can probably find it out with the command `grep -r --include "*.list" "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list* | grep -i "nvidia"`. It might be a server-side issue and the file is already provided corruptly by the repo maintainer, which would mean we have to contact them and/or file a bug report.

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list:deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64 /

Comment: I have nvidia 375 installed on my system which supports nvidia 1060 graphics card. According to repos, I guess, there is no entry for 375? Am I right?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the contents of your local `/var/lib/apt/lists/developer.download.nvidia.com_compute_cuda_repos_ubuntu1604_x86%5f64_Release` file?

Comment: Don't forget to notify me with a comment when you updated your question with the requested information. Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have similar distro and issue, thus added the content of the file

Comment: @m-ric please ask a new question

Comment: @Zanna this is the same issue. If I raise a new issue, someone _clever_ will tell me its duplicate... Anyway Z3nGuru's answer mentions a launchpad ticket where someone sent the bug report to nvidia.

Comment: @m-ric hmm if the bug report applies to you, then the question would be off-topic since bug reports are off topic :( But editing your own details into someone else's active question is not really OK in my opinion - you have no way of knowing that their file is the same as yours even if you have the same symptoms

Answer (score 1):

I also have similar issue on Ubuntu 16.04. Seems that release file use wrong date format. You can read about it here.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1649086

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Linux Mint 18 (corresponds to Ubuntu Xenial 16.04). Previous answers did not solved the problem for me.
I don't recall how I installed CUDA, but to get around this issue, I removed the sources list entry:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-8-0-local.list
```